# Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am learning react-router v4 and I tried creating a simple application. I created a React app using `create-react-app` cli.
My `routes.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../components/Home';
import ContentOne  from '../components/ContentOne';
import ContentTwo  from '../components/ContentTwo';

const routeConfig = [
  { path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: Home
  },
  { path:'/home',
    component:Home
  },
  { path: '/contentOne',
    component: ContentOne
  },
  { path: '/contentTwo',
    component: ContentTwo
  }
]

const Routes = () => {
   return (
      <Router>
      <Switch>
       {routeConfig.map((route, index) => {
           <Route path = {route.path} component = {route.component} exact = {route.exact} />
       })}
       </Switch>
      </Router>
   );
}
export default Routes;
```

`App.js` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import './App.css';
import SideNav from './components/SideNav';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <SideNav /> 
      <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`Index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Routes from './routes/Routes.js';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
<App>
<Routes />
</App>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

When I try to run the application I get an error stating "cannot read property 'history' of undefined". I tried debugging but I couldn't figure out where exactly the problem lies. Could anyone suggest to me where I am going wrong?

I have the following error in console:

> The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: Where exactly are you using Link, can you add that

Answer (score 0):

Try to add {history} inside the BrowserRouter => 
 `import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, history} from 'react-router-dom';`